# Use Angular Flex Layout custom breakpoints to Show/Hide elements

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am working on implementing custom breakpoints for the flex layout by extending the `ShowHideDirective`.

My custom directive is below.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { ShowHideDirective } from '@angular/flex-layout';

const selector = `[fxHide.xs.ngb], [fxHide.sm.ngb]`;
const inputs = ['fxHide.xs.ngb', 'fxHide.sm.ngb'];

@Directive({ selector, inputs })
export class CustomShowHideDirective extends ShowHideDirective {
  protected override inputs = inputs;
}
```

I am also defining a token like below.

```
import { BreakPoint, BREAKPOINTS } from '@angular/flex-layout';

const CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS: BreakPoint[] = [
  {
    alias: 'xs.ngb',
    mediaQuery: 'screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 599.98px)',
  },
  {
    alias: 'sm.ngb',
    mediaQuery: 'screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959.98px)',
  },
];

export const CustomBreakPointsProvider = {
  provide: BREAKPOINTS,
  useValue: CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS,
  multi: true,
};
```

In a shared module I declare and provide the directive and the provider

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CustomShowHideDirective],
  providers: [CustomBreakPointsProvider],
  exports: [CustomShowHideDirective],
  imports: [CommonModule, FlexLayoutModule],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And in the template I am using the directive like so:

```
<div fxLayout="column">
  <span>Some text</span>
  <button fxHide.sm.ngb="true" >Get started</button>
</div>
```

Why is the button element not hidden when the viewport is < sm.ngb?

Am I missing more configuration with this implementation?